# Jquery wont work in the included php file if address is via get

Tags: php, jquery, get, include

I have a problem with my script..

```
if (!isset($opt)) {

        input type="button" value="Add Item" class="add_item"
        input type="button" value="Delete Item(s)" class="del_item"

} else if ($opt == 'add') {    
    inculde("items_add.php");
} else if ($opt == 'edt') {
    //page for edit
} else if ($opt == 'del') {
    //page for delete
}
```

This is the code in the items_add.php

```
input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel_add"
```

And this one is on the external js file that holds all the jquery,

```
$('.add_item').click(function() {
    window.location = location.pathname+'?opt=add';
});

$('.cancel_add').click(function() {
    alert('asd');
});
```

My problem is this, the .add_item click works fine, but after I navigated to its link, the jquery for .cancel_add won’t work anymore. All elements that is in the items_add.php, won’t work if bind jquery with it.

- i dont have any syntax error i cant insert tags in here, maybe logical errors??
- the items_add.php will only be included when the get opt is equals to add but all the jquery within that doesn't work

Comment: You should really correct your code posted here.

Comment: i cant fix the code cause i cant put elements in the post yet..

Answer (score 0):

The code for checking isset should work like below

```
$opt = $_GET['opt'];
if (!isset($_GET['opt'])) {

        input type="button" value="Add Item" class="add_item"
        input type="button" value="Delete Item(s)" class="del_item"

} else if ($opt == 'add') {    
    inculde("items_add.php");
} else if ($opt == 'edt') {
    //page for edit
} else if ($opt == 'del') {
    //page for delete
}
```

Comment: i already have that get in the top of my page... luckily my friend already solve my problem btw thanks! :)

Comment: ill post the answer later because my reputation is 100 below by that i cant answer my question within 8 hours after posting it..

Comment: the solution is that your script must not be inside the document.ready function